# Reading in a matrix to R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a matrix in a file in the following format:

```
         V1        V2        V3        V4        V5       V6        V7
[1,] 17.67787 12.375978 12.007860 16.089949 24.864464 37.64243 42.711561
 ...
[10,] 42.89655 21.535867  7.975470  6.580414 10.326551 11.06297 11.201733
        V8       V9      V10       V11       V12       V13       V14
[1,] 30.41993 35.46864 16.97427 10.992030 11.408483 17.417670 33.815149
 ...
[10,]
```

10 rows and N column vectors laid out in sets of 7 columns.

How would one go about reading this  into R as a matrix?

scan is throwing an error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got 'V1'
```

If I try to call "as.matrix(read.table(..))"

I get:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 11 did not have 8 elements
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to post an actual `head -11` of the file in question. Having said that, if additional column headers (like `V9`- `V16`) are really interspersed within the file, then you'll need to use `readLines`, roll up your sleeves and do some post-processing.

Comment: Editing my post to include an actual extract of the files I need to read in.

Comment: @akun I get: Error in read.table("centroid0.txt", fill = TRUE, header = TRUE) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Comment: @raf please check my solution below.  I just copied the data from pastebin and run it using `readLines(textConnection(` or you can just read it from file by `readLines("name.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
 lines <- readLines(textConnection("V1 .... #... all the data you showed in `pastebin`
                 ...   33.21421"))
```

If you are reading it from a  `file`

```
 lines <- readLines("raf.txt")
 lines1 <- gsub("\\[.*]","",lines) #remove the `[,number]` part in the beginning
 library(stringr)
 lines2 <- str_trim(lines1) #remove the trailing/leading spaces
```

Here, I am splitting the lines2 into groups in a `list` using an index created by `grep` and `cumsum` so that each set of new group has a header and the data.  Then read the files in the `list` using `lapply` and `read.table`

```
  lst1 <- lapply(split(lines2, cumsum(grepl("^V", lines2))), 
                  function(x) read.table(text=x, header=TRUE))
  names(lst1) <- NULL
  res <- do.call(`cbind`, lst1)
```

If you want to convert it to matrix

```
 m1 <- as.matrix(res)
 dim(res)
 #[1]  10 128

 res[1:3,1:3]
 #       V1       V2       V3
 #1 17.67787 12.37598 12.00786
 #2 29.44688 19.44888 15.06014
 #3 30.49377 19.64495 11.15946
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a text object, `'txt'`,  that conforms to your original description.

```
dput(txt)
"         V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8\n [1] 10074 10146 10079 10091 10040 10066 10009 10152\n [2] 10137 10136 10032 10139 10038 10122 10123 10095\n [3] 10046 10120 10062 10061 10149 10029 10030 10059\n [4] 10003 10028 10148 10050 10057 10100 10144 10084\n [5] 10076 10012 10114 10073 10026 10135 10130 10083\n [6] 10007 10119 10063 10078 10086 10160 10125 10087\n [7] 10031 10090 10021 10092 10093 10067 10106 10129\n [8] 10004 10102 10113 10134 10042 10064 10037 10140\n [9] 10101 10156 10060 10121 10097 10002 10109 10033\n[10] 10075 10096 10024 10089 10115 10147 10036 10103\n         V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16\n [1] 10153 10107 10049 10143 10047 10126 10039 10018\n [2] 10065 10127 10048 10133 10108 10124 10117 10077\n [3] 10105 10051 10131 10069 10098 10058 10088 10006\n [4] 10132 10104 10112 10138 10128 10027 10043 10145\n [5] 10010 10072 10151 10111 10110 10052 10020 10082\n [6] 10023 10016 10044 10158 10159 10041 10155 10019\n [7] 10099 10008 10094 10142 10045 10068 10070 10015\n [8] 10013 10080 10053 10071 10085 10014 10056 10034\n [9] 10022 10011 10150 10054 10154 10035 10081 10118\n[10] 10116 10055 10017 10005 10025 10157 10141 10001"

 tcon <- textConnection(txt) # the first description did not have commas
```

In place of `txt` you can substitute a file() call; the principle being that you can read incrementally for a connection:

```
 cbind( read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),  # first 11 lines
        read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE))  # second 11

        V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8
[1]  10074 10146 10079 10091 10040 10066 10009 10152
[2]  10137 10136 10032 10139 10038 10122 10123 10095
[3]  10046 10120 10062 10061 10149 10029 10030 10059
[4]  10003 10028 10148 10050 10057 10100 10144 10084
[5]  10076 10012 10114 10073 10026 10135 10130 10083
[6]  10007 10119 10063 10078 10086 10160 10125 10087
[7]  10031 10090 10021 10092 10093 10067 10106 10129
[8]  10004 10102 10113 10134 10042 10064 10037 10140
[9]  10101 10156 10060 10121 10097 10002 10109 10033
[10] 10075 10096 10024 10089 10115 10147 10036 10103
        V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16
[1]  10153 10107 10049 10143 10047 10126 10039 10018
[2]  10065 10127 10048 10133 10108 10124 10117 10077
[3]  10105 10051 10131 10069 10098 10058 10088 10006
[4]  10132 10104 10112 10138 10128 10027 10043 10145
[5]  10010 10072 10151 10111 10110 10052 10020 10082
[6]  10023 10016 10044 10158 10159 10041 10155 10019
[7]  10099 10008 10094 10142 10045 10068 10070 10015
[8]  10013 10080 10053 10071 10085 10014 10056 10034
[9]  10022 10011 10150 10054 10154 10035 10081 10118
[10] 10116 10055 10017 10005 10025 10157 10141 10001
```

This does the same actions on a longer file. And conversion to a matrix remains trivial:

```
txt <-readLines(file("~/Downloads/YjwpsANG.txt"))
tcon <-textConnection(txt)
X <- cbind(  read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE), 
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
 read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE), 
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE), 
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE), 
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE), 
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE), 
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE), 
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE), 
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE),
read.table(text= readLines(tcon,n=11), header=TRUE) )
```

Comment: I may have explained poorly. I want the matrix to be read in as a 10xN matrix in R so I can then do matrix operations on it.

Comment: I gave you a 10 X N dataframe. Just convert to a matrix with the `data.matrix` function.

Comment: Actually this does not seem to be working. I am just getting the same 11 lines over and over again...

Comment: Post the text file or a link to a public location.

Comment: You say "it wasn't working", but when I do it by reading from a textConnection object I do not get repeated reads of the top of the file. You need to show your code when not getting expected results.The ambiguity in the phrase "it's not working" can be either in the manner of failure but also in the meaning of "it".

Comment: Sorry about any ambiguity. I mean when I use your exact code as posted, but rather than a text object I make a connection to a file I get the same 11 lines repeated. There is no incremental read from the file.

Comment: Needs to be a textConnection.